# How to make \lstinputlisting applicable to file paths with spaces?

Tags: listings, external-files, input, paths

I am using the `listings` package and the path to the source code contains some spaces. 
For example, the path can be `/some dir/sub dir/file 1.txt` and
`\lstinputlisting{/some dir/sub dir/file 1.txt}` does not work.

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In windows/miktex it works if you quote the name:

`\lstinputlisting{"some dir/sub dir/file 1.txt"}`

Comment: It works. Thanks @Ulrike Fischer! For others: Use "path to the file" rather than ``path to the file''.

Comment: +1 Works also for me with TeXLive 2011 under Linux. My first attempt to use an extra set of braces doesn't work (Error: `Too many }'s`).

Comment: As a note this does not appear to work on TeXLive2011/Win7 ! Package Listings Error: File `''C:/Users/MyName/Documents/Uni/Principles of
Programming/cs2303/Assigments/Assigment 3/atom/atom(.cpp'')' not found.

Comment: Where do the braces around .cpp comes from?